# Scroll animation buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons with position:fixed on my website. What i need is to while clicking on a top button the window scrolls top on 300px,  the same with bottom, it scrolls bottom on 300px.
Any ideas how to make this?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scroll down:

```
$("#buttonUp").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: window.scrollY + 300},
        'slow');
});
```

scroll up:

```
$("#buttonDown").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: window.scrollY - 300},
        'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.scrollBy(x, y)
```

e.g.

```
window.scrollBy(0, 300);
```

or

```
window.scrollBy(0, -300)
```

If you are using jQuery, you may use:

```
$(window).scrollTop(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$( ".yourButtonUpClass" ).on('click', function(){
    window.scroll(0, 300); 
});

$( ".yourButtonDownClass" ).on('click', function(){
    window.scroll(0, -300); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First variant works for me! Thanks!

```
$("#scrollBot").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: window.scrollY + 300},
            'slow');
    });

    $("#scrollTop").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: window.scrollY - 300},
            'slow');
    });
```